# Create Filter on Google Analytics for Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics on a mobile app for Android and iOS. 
The app is already configured with Google Analytics SDK and working properly.

Now I need to allow access to statistics for a client, but he can't see all the information the app views.
So, I created a new view for this customer, and would like to add filters to exclude / include the data he can see. However, the option to create filter don't appears to me in Google Analytics.

Additional Information:

- My user has administrator permission;
- I'm trying to create the filter by going to Administrator> Account> Property> Views> Filters.
- I have another account for a website in Google Analytics, and in this account I can create the filters.

Print screen:
[image: AZ]

Comment: Are you sure your going to the correct area. Admin, View (Rightest hand side) then filters?!

Comment: Hi! I think that I am on correct area. The same that I go to create filters for website account. I added a screenshot on question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem!

I wasn't with admin permission on ACCOUNT level. I was with admin permission only on VIEW level.

I added the permission on ACCOUNT level and now I can see the Create Filter button.